# Desperate to find out the name of this font!

Tags: fonts, font-identification

I need to know the name of this font:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like [Adrien Frutiger's Meridien](http://www.myfonts.com/search/meridien/fonts/) to me.

Comment: [I'd say you're right](http://i.imgur.com/TbsJI.gif)